"The thread owner has archived or deleted this conversation" Error when using Meta Graph Api for Instagram
I have my own instagram account and i have created an app in meta for my account automation.
Everytime i automate private replying to a DM, i get below error after sometime.
{
  "error": {
    "message": "The thread owner has archived or deleted this conversation, or the thread does not exist.",
    "type": "IGApiException",
    "code": 100,
    "error_subcode": 2534001,
    "fbtrace_id": "AgLmAH4eepLIf1PqLBN3y4J"
  }
}

When i reply with a comment, i get this below error.
{
  "error": {
    "message": "This API call does not support the requested response format",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 20,
    "error_subcode": 1772111,
    "is_transient": false,
    "error_user_title": "Create Comment Failed - Spam Detected",
    "error_user_msg": "To protect the Instagram community, your comment was flagged as spam and could not be added. Please review your comment's content and try again.",
    "fbtrace_id": "Aj9iw77tVvnd-loKZG7ULPy"
  }
}

There is no documentation for these error code on https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/error-codes/

My meta app is verified.
I am using long lived access token in api calls.

Everything seems fine, why is instagram blocking my automation? How is same working with manychat?
Intially i found some reference to verify my app to prevent this error. So, i have verified my meta  app with meta.
